# How to pull/push from/to GCR from GKE node

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I'm building an application that I will run in GKE. This application will use shell commands (for now) to build docker images and try to push them to GCR. I'm finding that when I try to do this from a pod running in GKE I get authentication problems. I'm having trouble figuring out why these authentication problems are happening.

Here's a list of all of the debugging I've done so far. At the highest level, my GKE clusters have the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write` oauth scope. When I examine the permissions on the underlying GCE instance, I see these permissions - note the `Read Write` value for `Storage`:

[image]

Now, when I SSH into that instance using the console and list the docker images I see the image used by GKE when spinning up my pod:

```
paymahn@gke-prod-478557c-default-pool-e9314f46-d9mn ~ $ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
gcr.io/gadic-310112/server                                              latest              8f8a22237c31        2 days ago          1.85GB
...
```

However, if I try to manually pull that image while SSH-ed into the GCP instance, I get an authentication problem:

```
paymahn@gke-prod-478557c-default-pool-e9314f46-d9mn ~ $ docker pull gcr.io/gadic-310112/server:latest
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

I also looked at the service account `65106360748-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` which is the default compute instance service account. Here are the permissions it has (I manually added the `Storage Object Creator` role):

[image]

Adding the `Storage Object Creator` role to that service account didn't help.

Is my approach to authentication here fundamentally flawed? It seems like I have all the right pieces in place to pull/push from GCR from GKE. Maybe there's an extra step I need to do for the `docker` client to authenticate?

Comment: Can you try to run `gcloud auth configure-docker`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to:

1. make a service account with the `roles/storage.objectAdmin`
2. generate a key for that service account
3. store that key as a secret in GKE
4. Mount that secret into my pods
5. run `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <path to key>`
6. run `gcloud auth configure-docker`

Once all of that was done, my pods could pull from and push to GCR.